# My database has been deleted suddenly on the server how to recover it?

Tags: sql-server, database, data-recovery

I'm running an application on windows server that connect to a SQL Server database.

Today, when I opened SQL Server Management Studio, I was surprised the database is not in the list of the databases!

I don't know what's the reason. I searched in the server files but I can't find the database and also in the recycle bin.

I put my database in `C:\db\myWeb.mdf` and suddenly it's been removed!

Can anyone tell me how to recover the database?

UPDATE:
I used stealer phoenix to find the database files deleted on disk but unfortunately i didn't find the db then i tried to add new database with the same name of the deleted db but SQL management studio said that the database "MyWeb" already exist! that's mean it's some where in the server but i couldn't find it ?! .

Comment: "it's very important" - hope you have a backup

Comment: actually i have a backup of the database but there're new records aren't in the last backup .

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do when the actual database files are missing is restore a backup of your server.

Optionally, when you have no backup, you could use a hard disk recovery tool (like Runtime GetDataBack to find the database files deleted on disk).

Comment: I used stealer phoenix to find the database files deleted on disk but unfortunately i didn't find the db then i tried to add new database with the same name of the deleted db but SQL management studio said that the database "MyWeb" already exist! that's mean it's some whare in the server ?! .

Comment: Then recovery is the only possibility. You can't prevent data loss in this case.

Comment: what do you mean by recovery (recover from what) ?